# Check all value of specific index in array object is Null or not?

Tags: php, arrays, object, unset

I have one array object in php.

I want to unset all index which contains null value for all inside objects.

example :

$data like

```
Array (
 [0] => Array (
             [address] => 123
             [address1] => asddff
             [address3] =>
           )
[1] => Array (
             [address] => 123
             [address1] =>
             [address3] => 
           )
[2] => Array (
             [address] => 123
             [address1] => asddff
             [address3] => 
           )
[3] => Array (
             [address] => 123
             [address1] => asddff
             [address3] => 
          )
)
```

example :
So address3 index is null for all array object so I want to make it unset for all object. 
address1 is not null for all so I need it. only unset address3 index for all.
Steps :

1. Want to check what indexes are null for all data.
2. Unset all those indexes.

So result should be like :

```
Array (
 [0] => Array (
             [address] => 123
             [address1] => asddff
           )
[1] => Array (
             [address] => 123
             [address1] =>
          )


[2] => Array (
             [address] => 123
             [address1] => asddff
           )
[3] => Array (
             [address] => 123
             [address1] => asddff
          )
)
```

Comment: What you have tried so far post your attempts

Comment: array_filter for you.

Answer (score 0):

Iterate and pass by reference as you unset.

```
foreach ($arr as &$a) {
    if (empty($a['address3'])) {
        unset($a['address3']);
    }
}

var_dump($arr);
```

Comment: Can't we simply use `empty($a['address3'])` instead of `!isset($a['address3']) || $a['address3'] === ""`

Comment: didnt know that one. That can be used as well.

Answer (score 0):

I think **array_filter** would do what you want to do

```
$data_filtered = array_filter($data, function ($obj) {
    return  !is_null($obj['address2']);
});
var_dump($data);
var_dump($data_filtered);
```

Well, storing filtered value in new variable is just an example, you do whatever you are trying to do.

Answer (score -1):

Simply use [`array_filter`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) along with [`array_map`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) like as

```
print_r(array_map('array_filter',$your_array));
```

Comment: This will get rid of "address2". I believe OP wants that one to stay.

Comment: Nope _Want to check what indexes are null for all data.
Unset all those indexes._ @CodeGodie

Comment: in that case, you got it.

Comment: it will rid of  '[1]['address1']' also.  If index address1 is null for all [0],[1],[2] then only need to rid of. Just like index address3 is null for all. So it should be unset for all. Not 'address1' index as it is not null for every one.

Comment: Then you need to check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32786884/2899618) answer